# Defining format for fscanf with "%s\t,\t

Tags: php

hey guys was hoping you could help me out,

I am relatively new to php and trying to read a file that is formatted as such

```
asdf    ,   asdf    ,   asdf
```

i.e a string followed by a tab, comma and another tab, then another string followed by a tab, a comma and another tab, then another string, then end of line (if theres another line).

I am learning regular expressions (from here http://weblogtoolscollection.com/regex/regex.php ) but dont think they you apply regular expressions in fscanf?

basically my code is

```
$file=fopen("sites.txt","r");
while($line=fscanf($file,"...")){
    list($a,$b,$c)=$line;
echo "$a    $b    $c   <br>";


}
```

so basically I want help on what should come in place of the "...", and also an explanation on how its working cause ive been googling for quite a while and cant seem to find what i am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`fgets`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) in this case. It is useful for reading files line-by-line. Use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to extract the column values (use `preg_split` if the delimiters are too fancy):

```
$file = fopen("sites.txt", "r");
while(($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
    list($a, $b, $c) = explode("\t,\t", $line, 3);
    echo "$a $b $c<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use fgetcsv() to split each line you read on the comma, then walk the resultant array trimming the tabs

```
$file = fopen("sites.txt", "r"); 

function myTrim(&$item) {
    $item = trim($item);
}


while(($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) { 
    array_walk($line,'myTrim');
    list($a, $b, $c) = $line; 
    echo "$a $b $c<br>"; 
}
```

or

```
$file = fopen("sites.txt", "r"); 
while(($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) { 
    array_walk($line,
        function (&$item) {
            $item = trim($item);
        }
    );
    list($a, $b, $c) = $line; 
    echo "$a $b $c<br>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
<?php
$matches = array();
preg_match_all("/(.+),(.+),(.+)/i",file_get_contents('sites.txt'),$matches);

foreach($matches[0] as $key=>$val){
  print "{$matches[1][$key]}  {$matches[2][$key]} {$matches[3][$key]}<br />";
}
```